# Adding checkbox and radion button to a new content type

Tags: drupal

How to add check box and Radio button to a new content type in drupal ?.It is not present in the available list of fields.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [List](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/list) module.

> The List module defines various fields for storing a list of items,
>   for use with the Field module. Usually these items are entered through
>   a select list, checkboxes or radio buttons. This module is an internal
>   element of the Field API.

[image]